# How to compose my loop?

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I have a number of filenames defined in my script and I would like to know how to run actions against all of them. The filenames simply look like:

```
fileName1 = "Path\to\file1"
fileName2 = "Path\to\file2"
"   "
fileName15 = "Path\to\file15"
```

How would I compose the loop to say "for every file in 'fileName', do 'x'"?

Many thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of filenames, so, use a list:

```
filenames = ["path/to/file1", "path/to/file2", "path/to/file3"]
```

Now, you can iterate:

```
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r') as my_file:
        # do something
```